# Console Application Release exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, compilation, publish

I have a console app that has lines of code like this:

```
#if DEBUG 
    dataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
#endif
```

I noticed that if I grab the **exe** from **Project\bin\Debug** folder the above code still runs.

I need to now publish this exe somewhere (it's going to be a scheduled task that runs and does some data crunching). But the **Project\bin\Release** folder does not have anything in it. So how do I obtain the Release exe, without going through the publish wizard (since that will just give you an installation package)?

Comment: Build in Release mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to switch your Solution Configuration from "Debug" to "Release". You can do this at the top of Visual Studio, or within the Project Properties under the Build tab. When you next build your project, the output files will be placed in the Release folder.

Additional info: When you build your project, its location has nothing to do with how it's compiled. The compiler runs based on whatever configuration you have it set to. So an executable created while in the Debug configuration will always run as if it was Debug, no matter where you put it. Same with Release, and any other build configurations you might have.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for, easy switch. I was aware of the location, but I assumed VS puts the Debug builds into Debug folder and Release builds into Release folder.

Comment: It does. However, it will not build for every configuration at the same time by default. You need to tell it which build configuration you want.